# NullPointerException while use getter

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Hello I have a problem with getter in my custom class, I don't know why it returns null every time. I'm setting value after response from server when it is without any errors. While I'm debugging, I see that response from server is OK and new instance of my object is created but when I try to get it in my activity there is a null. Here is couple lines of code where is a problem (in my opinion).

method from my custom class:

```
 public void responseFromServer(){
    showProgressDialog();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    TitleInterface titleInterface = retrofit.create(TitleInterface.class);
    Call<MovieResponse> call = titleInterface.getMovie(API_KEY,movie);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
            List<Movie> movieList =  response.body().getMovieList();
            ItemAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(context.getApplicationContext(),generateData(movieList));
            setItemAdapter(itemAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

and here is my Activity:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_list);

    movieListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.movieListView);
    String movie = getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG);

    presenter = new Presenter(this,movie);
    presenter.responseFromServer();
    item=presenter.getItemAdapter();
    movieListView.setAdapter(presenter.getItemAdapter());
    presenter.getItemAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    presenter.getProgressDialog().dismiss();
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: your call is asynchronous. the value is not set until after you try to get it.

Comment: how to resolve this?

Comment: What is that custom class? A service?

Comment: What is the exact error message? What line causes the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice this line: item=presenter.getItemAdapter(); because is always null

Comment: What is always null? I assume you mean `presenter`. Where do you declare and initialize this variable?

Comment: If you are referring to the `item=presenter.getItemAdapter();` line in `onCreate()`, then there is no possible way for this to throw an NPE. You initialize `presenter` 2 lines above that. The problem must occur somewhere else.

Comment: I declared 'presenter' and 'item' before 'onCreate' as private

Comment: In `Presenter` class i create new object called `ItemAdapter` (in void method) , then i want to set it and after get it in my activity

Comment: While im debuggin when i set breakpoint on line `setItemAdapter(itemAdapter)`, variable `itemAdapter` is not null, line after is null again..

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your request haven't finished when the view is created. If you want to make your call synchronous use this:

```
Call<MovieResponse> call = titleInterface.getMovie(API_KEY,movie);
Response<MovieResponse> responseBody = call.execute();

List<Movie> movieList =  response.body().getMovieList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using asynchronous calls in your app, so try to replace all necessary methods for updating UI from `onCreate()` to `onResponse()`. It should help. If you want to use Retrofit synchronous calls, the best practice for that is Loaders.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could supply a little more info, perhaps example code?